# PHP - Does a class need to have the same name as the file?

Tags: php, oop, class

Does a class need to have the same name as it's file.

Ex. class.mysql.php and inside it having class mysql (same)

Ex. class.fish.php and inside it having class mysql (diff)

Also can the format for a class file name be name.class.php or does it have to be class.name.php?

Thank You

Comment: The `class.` filename prefix convention is also not contemporary anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no link between the file name and the class name, you can name the classes in a file anything you want, have multiple classes or have no classes at all.  However, it is a good idea to develop a consistent convention to indicate what the file contains via its file name.

Edit:

See Jason McCreary's answer below as some of these conventions have changed.

Comment: Could you give some more examples? For example, I have a page named :"win-a-prize.php",which contains a form to submit the participants' contacts.  I am not sure if I should name the class as: _class WinaPrize extends Controller{}_, or else like _class WinApp extends Controller{}_

Comment: This answer might throw you off. Modern stuff like Laravel is using PSR-4 conventions, and it totally matters. Taken from Jason's answer below: the filename should match the class name exactly (with a .php extension) and the path should match the class namespace.

Comment: I have updated my answer to refer to Jason's answer.

Answer (score 5):

No on both accounts. These are simply common conventions of PHP developers. It's up to you if you wish to follow them.

#### Update

While my original answer is still technically correct, the conventions have changed in the last 5 years. Notably the [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) released PSR-0 and now [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). These outline file names of PHP classes as well as their path and how they should be namespaced and autoloaded.

You should read the spec for more details, but to paraphrase, the filename should match the class name with a `.php` extension and the path should match the class `namespace`.

For example, the class `Widget` with namespace `Acme`, would have the path: `base/path/Acme/Widget.php`.